# How to check whether Google Play Games account available on Android device?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I would like to know if there is an account available on an Android device which is registered as a Google Play Games account.

I am using Java, and LibGDX.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** 
*Google Play Games no longer needs a Google+ account as mentioned [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html)*

**Issue: Asking for unnecessary scopes**

```
 // Don’t do it this way!  
 GoogleApiClient gac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)  
           .addApi(Games.API)  
           .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN) // The bad part  
           .build();  
 // Don’t do it this way!
```

> In this case, the developer is specifically requesting the plus.login
>   scope. If you ask for plus.login, your users will get a consent
>   dialog.

**Solution: Ask only for the scopes you need**

```
// This way you won’t get a consent screen  
 GoogleApiClient gac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)  
           .addApi(Games.API)  
           .build();  
 // This way you won’t get a consent screen
```

> Remove any unneeded scopes from your GoogleApiClient construction
>   along with any APIs you no longer use.

---

**Original answer:**

A **Google Play Games** account is available when the user is signed in with a **Google+** account as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2954594?hl=en) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112479/google-play-games-without-google-plus), and that by itself is available if the user is signed in with a **Google** account, so our first approach would be:

1. Check if there is a Google Account *logged-in*.
2. Check if that user is *logged-in* Google+.

---

To check if the Android device has a **Google user logged-in**:

```
public boolean isLoggedInGoogle() {
    AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();

    for (Account account : list) {
        if (account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, to check if the Android device has a **Google+ user logged-in**.

You can try to start a login sequence with a Google API client, as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435869/how-to-check-whether-a-user-has-signed-in-google):

```
private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
}
```

---

You can also just make use of the [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils) of the [Play Games Services APIs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).
There are a few samples of how to achieve it in [this link](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I do use BaseGameUtils. But what happens if the user does have Google+, but is not yet signed in? And I have a second question: Would it make sense not to start Google Play Games when a user doesn't have a Google+ account yet? I think it might scare away users who prefer not to use Google+.

Comment: @Z0q Those were very good follow up questions! So I found an Android Developer post that said Google+ weren't needed anymore. I edited my answer already with the info. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html

Comment: @Z0q And... if you just want to remove the signing logic or modify, I'd recommend you to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046530/how-can-i-make-the-play-game-services-not-automatically-sign-in-at-the-startup

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies a lot for me. However, my question is `I would like to know if there is an account available on an Android device which is registered as a Google Play Games account.`. You told me how to see if the account is a Google account, but how do I know if it is also registered for Google Play Games?

Comment: Oh... you are right, I'm not even answering the original question with the edits. So... what I would do is: Try to login in the background: The blog post mentioned that "Players are prompted to sign-in once per account, rather than once per game". So if there is an account already logged in. You would receive something from the server.

Comment: @Evin1_ will this solution work for my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71151597/com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-17-api-games-api-is-not-availa