# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Games.API is not available on this device?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to implement Google Play Services leaderboard in my app, but I'm getting this exception when I call the leaderboard:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Games.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INVALID_ACCOUNT, resolution=null, message=null}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
leaderboardsClient
        .submitScoreImmediate(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), formattedValue)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ScoreSubmissionData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ScoreSubmissionData scoreSubmissionData) {

                leaderboardsClient.getAllLeaderboardsIntent().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                        startActivityForResults(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
        String temp = e.toString();
    }
});
```

Comment: What device are you running your app on?

Comment: I ran it on a S9+ and it works perfectly fine, but Note 10+ is getting this issue.